# Remove elements from array except particular one

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, array-splice

I have two arrays. First one is an array of indexes and second one is an array of objects. They look like this:

```
var nums = [0, 2];
var obj = [Object_1, Object_2, Object_3];
```

In this particular case I need to remove all "`obj`" elements except `obj[0]` and `obj[2]`. So the result will look like this:

```
obj = [Object_2]
```

There are also may be cases when `nums = [0, 1, 2]` and `obj = [Object_1, Object_2, Object_3]`; In that case I dont need to remove any elements.

The "`obj`" length is always greater than "nums" length.

So I started with finding only the elements that I need to save:

```
nums.forEach(function(key) {
    obj.forEach(function(o, o_key) {
        if (key === o_key) {
            console.log(key, o);
            // deleting remaining elements
        }
    });
});
```

The question: How can I remove elements that dont meets my condition? I dont need the new array, I want to modify the existing "obj" array. How can I achieve this functionality? Or should I use some another techniques?

Comment: why is in the first case to delete the given indices and in the second case the opposite?

Comment: I agree with @NinaScholz shouldn't the second case be `nums = []`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You coudld check if the length of the indices is the same length of the object array and return or delete the objects at the given indices.

It needs a sorted array for indices, because [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) changes the length of the array. (With an array with descending sorted indices, you could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of [`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight).)

```js
function mutate(objects, indices) {
    if (objects.length === indices.length) {
        return;
    }
    indices.reduceRight(function (_, i) {
        objects.splice(i, 1);
    }, null);
}

var objects = [{ o: 1 }, { o: 2 }, { o: 3 }];

mutate(objects, [0, 1, 2]);               // keep all items
console.log(objects); 

objects = [{ o: 1 }, { o: 2 }, { o: 3 }]; // delete items at index 0 and 2
mutate(objects, [0, 2]);
console.log(objects);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What about the opposite? If I want to save items at specified indexes like [0, 2] and delete the element under 1 index? What function instead reduceRight() is better to use? Sorry for disturbing)

Comment: @Luchnik, then i suggest to iterate the `objects`, get the max value of indices and check the actual index, then splice if necessary.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with a filter, assuming `nums` is an array on indexes of elements you want to keep.

```
obj = obj.filter((o, i) => nums.indexOf(i) > -1);
```

Comment: OP mentioned not wanting a new array

Comment: This doesn't create a new array, it filters the existing one

Comment: filter returns a new array - see first line in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control

Comment: Yes it does, but I took not wanting a new array in this question to mean that OP didn't want a new variable storing another array. If OP needs the array to be the _exact_ same array then my answer is incorrect. This answer starts with 2 variables holding arrays, and finishes with the same 2 variables holding arrays.

Comment: well too me it seems like the actual array object was important; having the same variable reference pointing to a new object is not really a use case worth considering (what's the point of it?) however maintaining the same object might be important - depending on what the object is used for

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the same array object, you need to use `splice` e.g. in a simple reverse `for` in order to not mess the indices:

```
for (var i=obj.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if (nums.indexOf(i) < 0) {
        obj.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

This is assuming the list of indices (nums) is ordered. If not, we first need to sort it:

```
var sortedNums = nums.sort(function (a, b) {  return a - b;  });
```

And then use the sortedNums to check the `indexOf`